# r - Use apply to take values of one column and calculate values for another column

Tags: r, apply

I have a data frame with measurements.

One column show the measurements in mm, and the other in units (which is a relative scale varying with zoom-level on the stereo microscope I was using).
I want to go through every row of my data frame, and for each "length_mm" that equals NA, I want to use the value in "length_units" to calculate "length_mm".

So far I've tried this code:

```
    convert_to_mm <- function(x) {
      x["length_mm"==NA] <- x["length_units"]/10
      x["length_mm"]
    }
    apply(zooplankton[,c("length_mm","length_units")], 1, convert_to_mm)
```

Sometimes I also have instances where both "length_mm" and "length_units" equals NA. In these cases I want to just skip the row.

Comment: This looks wrong: `x["length_mm"==NA] <- ...`. You should test your functions on single instances before trying to use them inside an apply procedure.

Comment: It frequently helps to get an answer faster if you provide [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with some sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easier than you're making it

```
# Which are the rows with bad values for mm? Create an indexing vector:
bad_mm <- is.na(zooplankton$length_mm)

# Now, for those rows, replace length_mm with length_units/10
zooplankton$length_mm[bad_mm] <- zooplankton$length_units[bad_mm]/10
```

Remember to use `is.na(x)` instead of `x==NA` when checking for NA vals. Why? Take a look at `NA==NA` for a hint!

Answer (score 0):

Almost there. You should use `is.na(myVariable)` and not `myVariable ==NA`